Access denied error for WMIC command tried connect to windows AD server having latest DCOM hardening updates
After installing latest updates on our windows server 2012 related to DCOM hardening(https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/dcom-authentication-hardening-what-you-need-to-know/ba-p/3657154), wmic command in ubuntu server failed to connect to windows server. Below is the command with output and ubuntu server details.
Ubuntu 22..04.4 LTS
wmic -U domain/user%password //10.10.10.211 --namespace //10.10.10.211//root/cimv2 "select Version from Win32_OperatingSystem"

Output of command
[librpc/rpc/dcerpc_util.c:1290:dcerpc_pipe_auth_recv()] Failed to bind to uuid 4d9f4ab8-7d1c-11cf-861e-0020af6e7c57 - NT_STATUS_NET_WRITE_FAULT
[librpc/rpc/dcerpc_connect.c:790:dcerpc_pipe_connect_b_recv()] failed NT status (c0000022) in dcerpc_pipe_connect_b_recv
[wmi/wmic.c:196:main()] ERROR: Login to remote object.
NTSTATUS: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED - Access denied


You've not provided any Ubuntu release details.

Updated the ubuntu server details

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.

Have you applied upgrades on your server?  as don't forget 18.04 reached EOSS some time ago, and ESM or Pro needs to be enabled to get upgrades now....   either way you're off-topic here now (the Ubuntu community doesn't support your release now; we're not Canonical)

Yes we upgraded the server to "Ubuntu 22..04.4 LTS", and still facing the same issue. I just wanted to know if wmic library support authentication level RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY as suggested in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5004442-manage-changes-for-windows-dcom-server-security-feature-bypass-cve-2021-26414-f1400b52-c141-43d2-941e-37ed901c769c
